# Code in if statement not getting hit

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I've been trying to figure out why this code is not getting hit.  The log says either "Success 1" or "Success 0" so I figured I could just use @"1" or @"0" in an if statement, but it's not going through either section.

```
     NSString *success = [JSON valueForKey:@"Success"];

    NSLog(@"Success %@", success);

    if (success  == @"1") {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginToInvite" sender:self];
    } else if (success == @"0")
    {
        _logInBtn.selected = NO;
        _popupLbl.hidden = NO;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Text" message:@"Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your check for string equality won't work as that is checking for identity (if the objects are the same object)

```
if (success  == @"1")
```

You instead, want to check equality, which in the case of strings is true if the values are the same. You should instead use this:

```
if ([success isEqualToString:@"1"])
```

Comment: Applied to objects, `==` compares pointers (addresses), not values.

Comment: @JamesWebster nothing wrong, just a further explanation. Never forget that Objective-C is C, with pointers at its core.

Answer (score 3):

NSString literal equality should be done with 
    [NSString isEqualToString:]
otherwise you are checking if the pointers to the objects are the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSString *success = [JSON valueForKey:@"Success"];

    NSLog(@"Success %@", success);

    if ([success  isEqual:@"1"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginToInvite" sender:self];
    } else if ([success isEqual:@"0"])
    {
        _logInBtn.selected = NO;
        _popupLbl.hidden = NO;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Text" message:@"Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare to a string value use isEqualToString:@"1"